# How do I to override login redirect on specific pages?

Tags: plugins, redirect, login, bbpress

## Description:

I'm using a WordPress plugin that applies specific redirects after logging in based on users and roles.

## The problem:

- I'm using a sidebar widget to allow users to log in on blog and forum (bbPress) pages.
- This widget doesn't have a perceptible redirect (stays on the same page).
- The plugin applies a redirect to this widget. I don't want it to.

## Information:

This is the documentation on how to extend the plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/other_notes/

It uses the following filters:

```
rul_before_user
rul_before_role
rul_before_capability
rul_before_fallback
```

...and the following variable for each:

```
$empty
$redirect_to
$requested_redirect_to
$user
```

I'm using bbPress 2.0 as a plugin for WordPress. The log-in widget comes with this.

## An example:

This code shows how to write custom redirect logic for the plugin I'm using:

```
function redirectByIP( $empty, $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user )
{
    $ip_check = '192.168.0';
    if( 0 === strpos( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ip_check ) )
    {
        return '/secret_area';
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

add_filter( 'rul_before_user', 'redirectByIP', 10, 4 );
```

I'm not sure how to manipulate this condition for it to read:

```
if (user has logged in using sidebar widget){
Keep on same page;
}
else{
Redirect the user as usual;
}
```

## My question(s):

- How do I set my log-in widget to ignore the redirect being applied by the plugin?
- Should I try to achieve this by tackling bbPress or the plugin?
- Any ideas on how to edit the above example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer:

I've figured this out myself.

Add the following code to your theme's functions.php file:

```
// Plugin by http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/
// Solution by http://www.dominornovus.com

function login_widget_redirect( $empty, $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user )
{
// If the referring page contains "/forums/"...
if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'/forums/') !== false)
{
$referringpage = $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER];
return $referringpage;
}
//Otherwise, check the referring page contains "/blog/"...
else if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'/blog/') !== false)
{
$referringpage = $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER];
return $referringpage;
}
// Otherwise, default to the plugin's redirect settings...
else
{
return false;
}

}

add_filter( 'rul_before_user', 'login_widget_redirect', 10, 4 );
```

This will effectively disable the plugin's redirect settings anytime a user logs in from a forum or blog page. The standard wp-login.php page will inherit the plugin's redirect settings.

You can find a detailed explanation of the code at my blog:

http://www.dominornovus.com/2011/11/14/restrict-peters-login-redirect-to-same-page-redirection/